# How to make Wordpress posts output sorted by the date specified in the post title? And how to display posts with a date in the title > = today's date?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm the first time I'm putting out the layout on Wordpress, so I apologize if the question is too simple and obvious:

I have a schedule for the upcoming master classes on the page. And I need the posts to be displayed in ascending order of the date (the date is indicated in the post's title, or, if it is more convinient, I can create a custom date field with the date). Date format is DD.MM.YY

And also, it is necessary that posts with past dates will be not displayed.

Please, tell me how to implement this?

Here is my current code for posts:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'numberposts' => 0,
    'category_name'    => schedule,
    'orderby'     => 'title',
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'include'     => array(),
    'exclude'     => array(),
    'meta_key'    => '',
    'meta_value'  =>'',
    'post_type'   => 'post',
    'suppress_filters' => true,
  );

  $posts = get_posts( $args );

  foreach($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post);
      ?>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="content-wrapper bg-gray schedule-card">
          <div class="day"><span><?php the_field('week_day') ?></span><span><?php the_title() ?></span></div>
          <a class="event" href="<?php the_field('mc_descr_link_1') ?>"><span class="event-time"><?php the_field('time-mc-1') ?></span><span class="event-name"><?php the_field('mc-1') ?></span></a>
          <a class="event" href="<?php the_field('mc_descr_link_2') ?>"><span class="event-time"><?php the_field('time-mc-2') ?></span><span class="event-name"><?php the_field('mc-2') ?></span></a>
          <a class="event" href="<?php the_field('mc_descr_link_3') ?>"><span class="event-time"><?php the_field('time-mc-3') ?></span><span class="event-name"><?php the_field('mc-3') ?></span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php
  }

  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you create custom field for those date fields. 
Or you can directly integrate that date field with native "date" field. 
But if you want to keep them separate from post_date field, then here is what you need to implement:

1. Create some custom field which contains those date values you are telling about. (CUSTOM_FIELD_WHICH_CONTAINS_DATE_VALUE)
2. Change $args array to this:

   ```
   $args = array (
   'category_name'    => 'schedule',
   'orderby'     => 'meta_value',
   'meta_key'=>'CUSTOM_FIELD_WHICH_CONTAINS_DATE_VALUE',
   'order'=>'ASC'
   'post_type'   => 'post');
   ```

Note that i have also removed unnecessary arguments from the array above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom field for date:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');//date format need to change according to your records
$args = array(
'numberposts' => 0,
'category_name'    => schedule,
'meta_key' => 'CUSTOM_DATE_FIELD_NAME',
'meta_type'=>'DATE',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'CUSTOM_DATE_FIELD_NAME',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>='
    )
),
'orderby' => 'meta_value_date',
'order' => 'ASC'
'exclude'     => array(),
'post_type'   => 'post',
'suppress_filters' => true,
```

);

Comment: Then change today date to:

Comment: $today= date('m.d.y');

Comment: Thanks for your help!
But it doesn't work...
Am I doing anything wrong?

With piece of code "'meta_query' => array( ...)" it doesn't work at all.

If these lines are commented, and I put " 'meta_key' => 'CUSTOM_DATE_FIELD_NAME' " instead - it show posts, but in wrong order.

I have a date in format DD.MM.YY (for example: 03.07.18, 10.01.19, 11.06.18).

But posts still diplayes in this order: 03.07.18, 10.01.19, 11.06.18 (firstable day number is compared, then - month, then - year).

Comment: instead of $post= get_posts($args); use $post= new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: Is it right?
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach($posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post); Because it really works wrong. I see like 50 empy posts on my page

Answer (score 0):

Change your CUSTOM_FIELD_DATE format to Y-m-d Ex:2017-02-27

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');//Format is 2018-01-28
$args = array(
'post_type'   => 'post',
'post_status'=>'publish',
'meta_key'=>'date_field',
'meta_type'=>'DATE',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'date_field',
        'value' => $today,
        'compare' => '>='
    )
),
);
$posts= new WP_Query( $args ); 
foreach($posts->posts as $post){ setup_postdata($post);
  ?>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
    <div class="content-wrapper bg-gray schedule-card">
      <div class="day"><span></span><span><?=$post->post_title;?></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php
```

}
    wp_reset_postdata();